# Windows 7: Accessing share over wifi

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, network-shares

In an office a PC with Win7 has shared folders for less then 10 users, it is accessible over the wired network but it asks for password on wifi then drops me with asking it over and over again, when I tried to use a username-password that is used on the Server it responded with:

```
\\SERVER not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. ...

Multiple connections to the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. ...
```

This message is confusing and it isn't a persistent reply. Yesterday it did reply this message consistently, today it does not, it just ask for user name and password again and again.

The same router is used when connecting over wired or wireless network. For internal network 169.254.144.x subnet is used, in wired mode we use static IP adresses in this range, and the DHCP is set to allocate adresses in this range. Verified it, positive. Even if I manually configure the address for the wifi adapter to the same ipv4 configuration as on the wired adapter the Server's folders will remain inaccessible.

An interesting thing that I can't explain is that pinging the name of the server over the wireless network will return a different IP address, one that is not in the 169.254.144.x range: 192.168.56.1

Any idea on how to get access to the shared folders over wifi network too?

Comment: I may be wrong, but based on the error message: `Multiple connections to the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed`, I'm wondering if the issue is that multiple connections to the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed.

Comment: Clearify please on this: how can I connect to the same user using more than one user name? When I connect to the PC I can specify only a single user name and password, how could I specify more than one user name? More users can access the shared resource when I have wired connections.
This error that I got occured only if I specified user/pass that were used only on the server PC not users that otherwise would access the shared folders. Now I dont get this error message, only the user/pass dialog appears again just as for users that have access over wired connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that I had virtual network cards like VirtualBox's, OpenVPN's TAP adapter and some VMWare network adapters...

A fast way to chek that the issue is really with multiple network adapters can be done by just disabling all network adapters except the wireless one and try to access then the shared folder.

To solve it I went into the wireless adapter's properties in the network connections window

- Selected `Internet Protocol Version 4` as I still use ipv4 adresses, click on properties
- `Advanced...` button, uncheck `Automatic metric` and  wrote there 2, as I have 1 for my wired network adapter.

The list of network adapters that can ordered in the `Network Connections` window's `Advanced` menu, in `Advanced Settings...` was configured but that seems to be not enough!

I figured it out by pinging myself that returned an ipv6 address and I was sure that I didn't enable ipv6 on the wireless adapter.